# Добавить в класс DetailView вывод формы для загрузки файла

Tags: python, django

День добрый. Подскажите, что требуется сделать, чтобы работала форма добавления файла к заявке. Класс вывода заявления представлен ниже уже с FormMixin

```
class MessageDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
    """Класс просмотра детальной информации по заявлению"""
    model = PfrMessage
    template_name = 'dob/dob_detail.html'
    form_class = AddFilesForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('dob_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MessageDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['form'] = self.get_form()
        return ctx

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Сама форма:

```
class AddFilesForm(models.ModelForm):
    """Форма добавления файла к заявке"""
    class Meta:
        model = PfrMessage
        fields = ('pfr_file',)
```

И непосредственно модель у меня выглядит:

```
class PfrMessage(models.Model):
    """Сообщения"""
    f_name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100)
    s_name = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField("Комментарий")
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_MESSAGE, verbose_name="Статус сообщения",
                                              default='new', max_length=40)
    pfr_file = models.FileField("Файл для загрузки", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-s_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось не верно применил Mixin. Исправил на ModelFormMixin, класс выглядеть стал:

```
class MessageDetail(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
"""Класс просмотра детальной информации по заявлению"""
model = PfrMessage
template_name = 'dob/dob_detail.html'
form_class = AddFilesForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('dou_list')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(MessageDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx['form'] = self.get_form()
    return ctx

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    # form = AddFilesForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return super(MessageDetail, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```